# How to completely remove unused resources when building android?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-resources

I have a resource group that I create randomly through another program.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Some of these resource groups are actually used, some are not.

This resource group belongs to another library, and my app imports and uses the library.

Since this group is constantly being updated, I don't want it to be removed from the project, I just want it to be excluded from the build output.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

The official documentation says that I can remove my unused resources through the shrinkResource function. So I set my app.gradle as below.

```
...
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro' <-- This is an empty file.
          
        }

...

dependencies {
    implementation project(':myResourceLibrary')
...
}
```

I also created keep.xml in res/raw for strict resource checking.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@raw/*" <-- This part is the same with or without it.
    tools:shrinkMode="strict" />
```

Ok, I ran the build and got the apk successfully. However, when checking the apk through the apk analysis of Android Studio, the resource was not removed.

The resource remains in the form below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x />
```

The build log states that the resource was processed as follows.

```
Skipped unused resource 'my_resource_file': 444 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 104 bytes)
```

Okay, I can say that the capacity reduction alone works, but I like here (https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking) I want unused files to be completely removed.

None of the documentation explains why this file can be completely removed, or why it cannot be completely removed.

Why doesn't the gradle know that the resource is not being used, but it doesn't delete the file? Can I remove that file?

I am working on a build using gradle 4.1.0 and I am building with the following command.

```
./gradlew --info assemble(MyProductFlavor)Release
```

Even if I use Android Studio's`Rebuild Project`, it will be in the same state as shown below.
[image]

Comment: You have built apk in Debug or Release mode ?  You should enable shrinking in your release build to remove unused code and resources

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with how resources are stored and how there are different ways to access them. From what I've heard, libraries which do source code modification may expect to find a resource when they found it as a file. So the prevent unpredictable results, they are replaced with a dummy value instead of removed. (This is all from memory and pieced together info I got from podcasts/blogs)

Comment: As far as removing the resource goes, I'm pretty sure its safe to remove it (unless you have a more complex build with different variants which depend on different resource sets or something like that). Though when uncertain, always try to look for references in the code and check if that resource actually isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

this part of code:

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro' <-- This is an empty file.
      
    }
```

going to delete unused resources and then minify your code(because no one can decompile your apk) and if you see that your apk also contains unused resources, because that apk is for debug and minify/shrink doesn't impact on debug apk but impact on release apk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think this is the apk obtained through the release build. I added the build command to the body.

Comment: So check this:
First put Build Variants on release, then Rebuild Project. At the end, set view to Project View then double click on release folder and then click on app-release.apk .

Comment: The same. After the Rebuild Project, I added the result for drawables that are not used in the apk file of the project directly.